# Android NDK, build_native.sh at cocos2d-x (Mac terminal)

Tags: android, macos, android-ndk, terminal, cocos2d-x

when i try to execute in a mac terminal -> build_native.sh

the terminal return to me the next line:

./build_native.sh: line 74: /Users/nameusr/Documents/Android/ndk/android-ndk-r9c/ndk-build: No such file or directory

someone knows how fix this?

the file exist and the android ndk is already installed.

Thanks

Comment: Does the mentioned file exist?  What is its ownership? Permissions?

Comment: i give a permissions for this file: chmod u+rwx ndk-build 
but exactly i don't know ehat is the ownership... can you tell me what is this?